# Logarithmic Sobolev embeddings

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, sobolev-spaces

It is well-known that $H^{\frac d2}(\mathbb R^d)=W^{\frac d2, 2}(\mathbb R^d)$ is not included in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$, but it seems that there are some logarithmic substitutes. Is it true for instance that
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)}\lesssim \big\Vert  \vert D \vert^{d/2}\ln(1+\vert D\vert) u\big\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}\,,
$$
or is there some analogous statement? Is there a clear connection with Gross' logarithmic Sobolev inequalities?

Comment: This works, you can just estimate $\|\widehat{u}\|_1$ with Cauchy-Schwarz. (I assume that $|D|$ is multiplication by $|\xi|$ on the Fourier transform side.)

Comment: You may look at the Brezis-Gallouet inequality.

Comment: @RaffaeleScandone, it might be helpful to state the inequality and provide a reference.

Answer (score 1):

A logarithmic correction to critical Sobolev embedding is given by the Brezis-Gallouet-Weinger inequality: [[Brezis-Gallouet]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0362546X80900681) [[Brezis-Weinger]](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03605308008820154):

\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)}\lesssim 1+\|f\|_{W^{d/p,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)}\ln^{(p-1)/p}(e+\|f\|_{W^{d/q+\alpha,q}(\mathbb{R}^d)}),\qquad p,q\in(1,\infty),\;\alpha>0.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Following Christian Remling suggestion, it seems that
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)}\le \gamma(d)\bigl\{
\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}+
\Vert \vert D\vert^{d/2} L(\vert D\vert) u\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}
\bigr\}
$$
with
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{dr}{L(r)^2 r}<+\infty.
$$